# What is the intuition behind Dirichlet's Class Number Formula?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As the title of the question suggests, what is the intuition behind Dirichlet's Class Number Formula being true? The Dirichlet Class Number Formula is$$h(\mathcal{O}_D) = -{1\over{D}} \sum_{n=1}^D n\left({{-D}\over{n}}\right)$$for $D > 4$, where $\left({{-D}\over{n}}\right)$ is the Kronecker symbol.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by "intuition". An instructive special case is the imaginary quadratic case, see [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/iqclassno.pdf). For a somewhat related MO question, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25707/intuition-for-a-formula-that-expresses-the-class-number-of-an-imaginary-quadrati).

Comment: It is a rather elegant doublue-counting argument, but in my humble opinion it is far from being "trivial" or "intuitive".

Comment: Duplicate?  [Intuition for Class Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/547496/)